# Is thread safe when I call readonly static members of struce in C++

Tags: c++, thread-safety

I have class that I'd like to call it like as *enum*:

```
struct mac_constant {
 private:
  static constexpr int SL_MAX_val = 5;
  static constexpr std::array<double,SL_MAX_val> r_SL{ 19.8, 40.16, 62.00, 83.84, 105.68 };
  static constexpr std::array<size_t,SL_MAX_val> n_TS_SL{ 160, 192, 256, 320, 384 };

 public:
  static constexpr size_t SL_MAX = SL_MAX_val;
  static constexpr double get_r_SL(const size_t SL_index) {
    return r_SL.at(SL_index);
  };
  static constexpr size_t get_n_TS_SL(const size_t SL_index) {
    return n_TS_SL.at(SL_index);
  };

  mac_constant() = delete;
  mac_constant(const mac_constant&) = delete;
  mac_constant& operator=(const mac_constant&) = delete;
};
```

I call it in main function:

```
int main () {
    int val = mac_constant::get_n_TS_SL(2);
}
```

Above code can pass compile and run fine [here](https://godbolt.org/z/zrmVBs) (seems single thread)

Because this struct is **readonly**, can't construct, copy,
I guess it's thread safe.

Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data in the class is constructed in a thread safe manner (magic_statics - C++11), and is static and none of the data it is referring to  will be changed during execution of the code.

So in this case, the answer is yes.  But if the data was calculated, it may start to have thread races, so I would not take this answer as a general case.

After the function main starts, then all static objects have been completely initialized.  That is they are in their *initial* state.

Any of these objects which are queried, can be done safely unless their state can change (which would break the `constexpr`.)

A correctly formed `C++` program works when an object is accessed with suitable `locks` in multiple threads, or for some period of time, the object is not modified in any way, it can be accessed without synchronisation from multiple threads.

So any object which is const (in your case for the lifetime of `main`) for some period of time can be accessed without any lock.  If there were deferred calculation of any of the data in the std::array, then that could cause a data-race which would cause the program to be ill-formed.

Comment: Does `calculated` means airthmetic such as `+`?